# How to stop of the node being touched on the screen? SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game where I have a node on the screen and when the player touches the screen the node just works, BUT I just want when the player taps on the node and then the action happens.

> Here is the code of what is going on.

```
var ballNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "balls.png")

var touchLocation = CGPoint()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

ballNode.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
ballNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.5, y:  self.size.height*0.9)

self.addChild(ballNode)

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
let positionInScene = touch.location(in: self)
let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene)

touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

let moveDown = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height*0.1, duration: 0.3)
let moveUp = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height*0.9, duration: 0.3)
let moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveDown, moveUp])
ballNode.run(moveSequence)
let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
ballNode.contains(pointOfTouch)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done this way.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        if ballNode.frame.contains(touchLocation) {

            let moveDown = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height*0.1, duration: 0.3)
            //let spin = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 1))
            //let spin = SKAction.repeat(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 1), count: 3)
            let spin = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 1)
            let moveUp = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height*0.9, duration: 0.3)
            let moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveDown, spin , moveUp])
            ballNode.run(moveSequence)
        }
    }
}
```

I've added a line for a spin action, there are 2 commented lines for more spinning. just choose which suits you best

Comment: Your welcome, Please select this as the right answer and if it helps you please up-vote it. I received a badge yesterday (Tenacious) on SO for having at least 20% of my accepted answers having no up-votes :(

Comment: You got it @RonMyschuk

Comment: By the way By any chance, do you know how to make the node rotate as in spin when they touched?

Comment: Thank you, I did it this way  let action = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -20, duration: 0.3)

Comment: You can get nodes right from the touch, no need to check ballNodes frame

Comment: Use `self.nodesAtPoint(touchLocation )`  iterate though them or filter out the ball node

Comment: @Knight0fDragon what's the advantage to this? isn't this a case of potato/potatoe?

Comment: Advantage is not all nodes have a frame, or the frame does not reflect the sprite.  Perhaps there is another node on top of the ballframe,  the list goes on and on.  So while your answer does solve this specific problem, I suggested a more versatile approach to help solve other problems that will come with advanced development.